# how to change directory on VsCode python coding (Win10)? Basical Question but i have tried

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

[image: 1]
This is my first question here,
I mainly use VSCode as IDE, and often play Python codes, and I stuck here,
'''

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os,sys
print(os.getcwd())
print('__file__:', __file__)
fileP = str(__file__).replace("c:\\", "")
print(fileP)
*print(os.chdir("C:\\Users\\playf\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\Lib\\site-packages\\tespy"))*
```

'''

Trackback is like below
'''

```
File "C:\Users\playf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\playf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\playf\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.103604\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\playf\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.103604\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\playf\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.103604\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 267, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(options.target, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Users\playf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\playf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\playf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\playf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\line4py\setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    os.chdir()
**TypeError: chdir() missing required argument 'path' (pos 1)**
```

'''

I tried another typing of pass like
'''

```
"C:\\Users\\playf\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\Lib\\site-packages\\tespy"
"Users\\playf\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\Lib\\site-packages\\tespy"
"/Users/playf/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Lib/site-packages/tespy"
"Users/playf/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Lib/site-packages/tespy"
```

'''

all is out,
is this problem about escape sequence or what?

Comment: You shouldn't generally need to `os.chdir()` in a program. (I can count the occurrences of doing so with two hands.) What are you actually trying to do? Why would you chdir to a site-package's directory?

Comment: The code you post works well on my machine(win10). Is there any other information you can provide for us to go further test, like have you import other .py file with class and directly use it? because class should be instantiated first then you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Why Win10 for programming?
You can install Ubuntu in 15 minutes and code fast and easily